# Calculating next 3 year anniversary of employee based on join date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Employee mysql db table with employee name and start date. I want to be able to calculate upcoming 3 year anniversary of each employee from today's date. (So for example, Jordan's next upcoming anniversary would be 08/25/2019, Lee's would be 09/22/2017, Mike's 10/26/2018)

```
id    name       startDate        
---------------------------
0     Jordan     08/25/2010          
1     Lee        09/22/2014          
2     Mike       10/26/2015
```

Inefficient brute force solution would be to generate all anniversary dates from startDate up to current date plus one date beyond today's date and then select it.

but there is got to be a more efficient SQL Query to display next upcoming anniversary for each employee based on today's date. Must be a way to use DATEDIFF somehow.

Comment: @KamilG How so? Next anniversary from today's date would have to be 08/25/2019.

Comment: What do you want to do for employees hired on leap day?

Comment: @CodeCrack leap day is a good question actually but I would assume you don't care so much. My answer and I believe the others would just assume the anniversary date would be on the 2/28 instead of 2/29.  here is a sqlfiddle that shows how mysql treats the addition of years to a leap day. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f35e91/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED

```
SELECT
  *
  ,CASE
    WHEN CURDATE() <= startDate THEN startDate + INTERVAL 3 year
    WHEN MOD((YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(startDate)),3) = 0
      AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) year) 
          <= (startDate - INTERVAL YEAR(startDate) year) 
      THEN startDate + INTERVAL (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(startDate)) year
    ELSE startDate + INTERVAL (year(CURDATE()) - YEAR(startDate) + 3 - MOD(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(startDate),3)) year
  END   as "Next3YrAniversary"
FROM
  TableName
```

SQL Fiddle to show you it working with the test cases: 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf276a/1

Anyway, the idea is as follows:

- `startDate is Today or in future if so just add 3 years`
- `Remainder of (Yesrs Diff / 3) = 0` `and` `if current month/day is <= month/day of startDate` if so anniversary is this year and hasn't occurred yet, so `add number of years between current date and startDate to startDate`.  To say it is in a slightly different way if it is `2016` and the anniversary is in `2016` it will see if the anniversary has happened yet this year or not.
- Else add to start date: `Number of years between Start Date & Now + 3 years - Remainder of (Years between Now and startDate / 3)`

A note about `YEAR()` vs `year`.  you could write `year()` or `YEAR()` I tend to capitalize my specific functions etc but year() function just gets the `INT` of the year of a date. So `YEAR(CURDATE())` means get the year of the current date e.g. `2016`, `YEAR(startDate)` gets the year of the `startDate` e.g. `2013`. `MOD()` gives you the remainder from a division so `2 / 3 remainder 1`

```
2016 - 2013 gives you 3 so remainder of 3/3 is 0
```

The lower case year which is not a function [without brackets] defines an INTERVAL type you could use day, year, month, etc.

```
date INTERVAL + 1 year = add 1 year to date
```

Another example is

```
startDate INTERVAL + NumOfYearsDiff year = add NumOfYearsDiff to startDate
```

In case 2 when comparing what I do is make both dates essentially `YEAR 0001` by subtracting the year integer out of the date and then compare which will tell me which date is later in the year to understand if the anniversary has already passed or is still coming up this year. `TIMESTAMPDIFF` does this automatically for you to a degree, but if you use then the aniversary date would be the next one e.g. `2019` if it is today in `2016`.  So if you want to show it as today you would still have to check the same condition I did, meaning no real reason to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

Here is a sqlfiddle side by side comparison of My Method, Spencer's, and Gordon's
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf276a/3

What it shows:

- If the anniversary is today Gordon's & Spencer's methods will show the next anniversary as today + 3 years.  Which could or could not be desired?
- Gordon's answer for future dates will show the startDate instead of startDate + 3 years

Comment: @CodeCrack let me know if this works out for you, if you want 5 year anniversary, 10 etc. just replace the 3s with 5 or 10.

Comment: I recommend testing this with three boundary cases.  One where the anniversary date is yesterday (should return yesterday + 3 years).  One where the anniversary date is today (no idea what the op wants here).  And one where the anniversary is tomorrow (should return Tomorrow).

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2c3d/1 shows that when the anniversary is "later this year", the code still adds 3 years, incorrectly.

Comment: I recommend using `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, then, now)`

Comment: @MatBailie I had started developing with TIMESTAMPDIFF but I was transferring logic from sql-server and I was getting a different and unexpected values. between it a ss datediff.  I believe in part because TIMESTAMPDIFF doesn't take into account leap years.  Anyway, I see your points now that I am back at my computer and I will show 2 ways to fix shortly

Comment: Hey Matt. It seems to work and look great but I don't quite understand case 2. Also why do you keep putting year in lines such as INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) year)  <-- what does that year lowercase do in YEAR()

Comment: @CodeCrack I edited to add a bit more but YEAR() is the function and capitalization doesn't matter where as year without brackets is an INTERVAL so INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) year would be how you would add or subtract 2016 years from a date [assuming current year is 2016]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do think it is a bit cumbersome, but you can do this in one statement.

I think logic that will work is to take the difference in years and round up to the nearest 3 years.  Then add this to the start date.  If this is greater than the current date, that is the next start date.  Otherwise, add three more years:

```
select t.*,
       (case when startdate + interval 3 + 3 * floor((year(curdate()) - year(startdate)) / 3) year > curdate()
             then startdate + interval 3 + 3 * floor((year(curdate()) - year(startdate)) / 3) year
             else startdate + interval 6 + 3 * floor((year(curdate()) - year(startdate)) / 3) year
from t;
```

Comment: This approach gets close, but I don't think this works for startdate '2013-09-30', given today's date of '2016-09-16'. The next "three year anniversary" from the start date would be in 14 days, '2016-09-30'.

Answer (score 0):

The approach in Gordon's answer is a good one. I just think a slight modification is necessary. To use:

`INTERVAL 0 +` in place of `INTERVAL 3 +`

and to use

`INTERVAL 3 +` in place of `INTERVAL 6 +`

I don't want to mess with Gordon's answer.

Here is a demonstration of the exact same approach, with slightly different syntax, and also adding a check for `startdate` in the future, where we would want to just add 3 years to `startdate` (to get the date of the first three year anniversary).

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , t.startdate
     , CASE
       WHEN t.startdate > DATE(NOW())
       THEN t.startdate + INTERVAL 3 YEAR
       WHEN t.startdate + INTERVAL FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,t.startdate,NOW()) /3)*3 YEAR > DATE(NOW())
       THEN t.startdate + INTERVAL FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,t.startdate,NOW()) /3)*3 YEAR
       ELSE t.startdate + INTERVAL FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,t.startdate,NOW()) /3)*3 + 3 YEAR
       END AS next_3yr_anniv
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY ...
```